# How to set pg_lsn value to PreparedStatement obj in java?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a logical slot replication in PostgreSQL 11.4 and I have to execute the following query:

```
SELECT lsn, xid FROM pg_logical_slot_peek_changes('inv_slot', '0/88768F28', NULL
                                           , 'include-timestamp','true'
                                           , 'include-types','false'
                                           , 'add-tables','public.personas')
```

If I use a Statement obj like this its Ok and execution is right:

```
stmt.execute("SELECT lsn, xid FROM pg_logical_slot_peek_changes('inv_slot', '0/88768F28', NULL
                                               , 'include-timestamp','true'
                                               , 'include-types','false'
                                               , 'add-tables','public.personas')");
```

But due to security reasons I have to use a PreparedStatement Object. So I wrote the following code:

```
PreparedStatement stmt2 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT lsn, xid FROM pg_logical_slot_peek_changes(?, ?, NULL\r\n" + 
                                    "                                          , 'include-timestamp','true'\r\n" + 
                                    "                                          , 'include-types','false'\r\n" + 
                                    "                                          , 'add-tables',?)");
                         stmt2.setString(1, "inv_slot");
                         stmt2.setString(2, "0/88768F28"); <--- A VALID pg_lsn
                         stmt2.setString(3, "public.personas");
                         stmt2.execute();
                         stmt2.close();
```

But using PreparedStament I have following error:

```
Error SQL: 0 ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe1 0x6c 0x69
```

Stacktrace line error is: `stmt2.execute();`

If I execute a PreparedStatement without a **pg_lsn** value, like NULL, execution is right. But if I set a value for pg_lsn a error appears.

If I print PreparedStatement obj, both of queries are identical but the PreparedStatement with pg_lsn value fails.

So, I think a PG_LSN is not a String and is a driver error, so, what PreparedStament method should I use to assign a pg_lsn value?

Comment: Try `cast(? as pg_lsn)` instead of just `?` for the lsn parameter

Comment: I believe there must be a mistake. None of your data would correspond to these three bytes. In ISO-8859-1 or WIndows-1252 encoding, these bytes would correspond to `áli`, which could be part of a French or Spanish string. So I assume that you supply data different from what you think. One option is to set `log_statement = all` and examine the log entry for the statement. It should contain the parameter values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it works! Can u post as a anwser please